# Binomial represented as polynomial operations

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I was doing some plotting on wolfram alpha and the following binomial

${n/2-n/4} \choose {n/4-5}$

was represented as:

$\frac{1}{480} ({\frac{n}{4}-4})({\frac{n}{4}-3})({\frac{n}{4}-2})({\frac{n}{4}-1})n$

I am curious if somebody can explain to me why this representation and what is the rationale behind it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We deal here with the notion of [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).

Let us first rewrite your binomial coefficient in a simpler way, using  classical formula: $\binom{N}{P}=\binom{N}{N-P}$:

$$\binom{n/4}{n/4-5}=\binom{n/4}{n/4-(n/4-5)}=\binom{n/4}{5}\tag{1}$$

A falling factorial is (indeed) defined as a polynomial with consecutive integer roots beginning at $0$ ; more precisely:

$$x_{(N)}:=x(x-1)(x-2) \cdots (x-N+1)\tag{2}$$

with the property:

$$\dfrac{x_{(N)}}{N!}=\binom{x}{N}\tag{3}$$

(this definition and this property can be found in the Wikipedia reference given above ; please note that this definition/property extends a property that we know as valid for integer values of $x$).

Setting $x=n/4, N=5$ (take care not to mix $n$ and $N$) and using (1),(2), and (3), it is easy to establish your identity.

**Remark:** you will see in the Wikipedia article the dual concept of rising factorial.

Comment: thank you so much Jean